# Getting packages in to an R evironment using Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

I created an environment in anaconda for R/Rstudio, do I need to install r packages for the environment in Rstudio or by activating the environment in conda and install them from the command line?

I ask because many times I look for a package in the environments tab of anaconda, but it is not listed there and when I go back to Rstudio and install it, it doesn't show as an installed package in my created r environment even though I activate the environment before I start r studio.

Comment: Rstudio is just an IDE for R (as it could be Atom or Geany)  thus whatever you are doing you need to deal with R directly and not with Rstudio (unless you are specifically interested in running the IDE)

Comment: When R is installed by Conda, then I have generally had a better experience managing entirely through Conda. The main issue is that Conda brings its own build tools/libraries along, and installing from within R/RStudio does not automatically find them, which can lead to failed package installs and missing dynamic libs. That said, for interactive work (day-to-day data science) I stick to a native installation with R installs. I only turn to Conda for hardened pipelines where I know exactly what needs installed up front.